Email builder button component doesn't work on all email clients
This is a screen shot of an email I built with Salesforce/Pardot from a client, on Outlook (They didn't say what OS). The button should have black text and padding on the left and right. It's a button component from the Pardot email template builder, and it looks fine when I view a test.

I understand that buttons are difficult to get to work on all client, and I know I can fix this using custom HTML, but why does a built-in Pardot component not work for a major email client? Am I doing something wrong?
